Netgear CAX80 router/gateway is apparently blocking Facebook messaging on a mobile device
I have a Samsung Galaxy S24 Ultra and my Netgear CAX80 router/gateway is apparently blocking Facebook messaging on the Samsung Galaxy S24 Ultrae.
I get the pop-up on the phone it switches to mobile data to send message. It's not happening all the time just half of the time. I have got to the point that I am rebooting router/modem daily.
I think its the built in security of the Netgear CAX80 causing this. but Netgear tech support will not help since I am out of the warranty.
I see there are other post on this problem but I am new to this site I can't add this comment.

i don't have any parental controls on Block Sites is off
